# How to add stateless component to a touchable component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add a stateless component to my button.

```
const button = ({onButtonPress, buttonText}) => {
 return (
   <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={() => onButtonPress()}>
     <ButtonContent text={buttonText}/>
   </TouchableHighlight>
 )
};
```

and get this error:

```
Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs (See ref "childRef"  
in StatelessComponent created by TouchableHighlight). 
Attempts to access this ref will fail.
```

I have read up on the issue but I am still new to javascript and RN and have not found a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

full code:

GlossaryButtonContent:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import Colours from '../constants/Colours';
import {
  arrowForwardDark,
  starDarkFill
} from '../assets/icons';

type Props = {
  text: string,
  showFavButton?: boolean
}

export default ({text, showFavButton} : Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {showFavButton &&
      <Image
        style={styles.star}
        source={starDarkFill}/>}

      <Text style={[styles.text, showFavButton && styles.favButton]}>
        {showFavButton ? 'Favourites' : text}
      </Text>

      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={arrowForwardDark}
        opacity={showFavButton ? .5 : 1}/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  favButton: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    color: Colours.darkTextHalf
  },

  text: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Bariol-Bold',
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colours.darkText
  },

  image: {
    marginRight: 20
  },

  star: {
    marginLeft: 10
  }
});
```

GlossaryButton:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import Colours from '../constants/Colours';
import ShadowedBox from './ShadowedBox';
import GlossaryButtonContent from './GlossaryButtonContent';

type Props = {
  buttonText: string,
  onButtonPress: Function,
  rowID: number,
  sectionID?: string,
  showFavButton?: boolean
}

export default ({buttonText, onButtonPress, rowID, sectionID, showFavButton} : Props) => {
  return (
    <ShadowedBox
      style={styles.container}
      backColor={showFavButton && Colours.yellow}>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.button}
        underlayColor={Colours.green}
        onPress={() => onButtonPress(rowID, sectionID)}>
        <GlossaryButtonContent
          text={buttonText}
          showFavButton={showFavButton}/>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </ShadowedBox>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 60,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
  },

  button: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: can you post the code of `ButtonContent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, Stateless components cannot have refs.

So, having a stateless component in the middle of the render tree will create a void in the ref chain, meaning you cannot access lower-down components.

So, the problem comes from trying to do this:

```
let Stateless = (props) => (
  <div />
);
let Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <Stateless ref="stateeee" />
  }
});
```

`TouchableHighlight` [needs to give a ref to its child](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableHighlight.js#L267-L272). And this triggers that warning.

**Answer**:

You can't actually make a stateless component a child of `TouchableHighlight`

**Solution:**

Use `createClass` or `class` to create the child of `TouchableHighlight`, that is `GlossaryButtonContent`.

See [this github issue for more info](https://github.com/QubitProducts/react-test-tree/issues/49#issue-114016058) and [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936)

Comment: thank you. Not sure if this is good practice but ended up just putting them in the same file: 

`const button = ({onButtonPress, buttonText}) => { const renderButtonContent = () => { return ( ... ); }; return ( <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => onButtonPress()}> {renderButtonContent()} </TouchableHighlight> ); }`

Comment: @Lance This does not look very readable. Why not leave them as separate components and use `React.createClass` ?It's not mandatory to use stateless components. And they don't add any benefits *yet* except reducing the clutter ( a benefit you'll lose if you use the code above ).

Comment: Sorry i tried but don't know how to format code in a comment. I thought React.createClass is getting depreciated in favour of extends React.Component. If stateless components don't add any benefits then why use them? Only to reduce code by 1 line?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot, another reason for my decision is that when making ButtonContent a component it gave me this error: `Touchable child must either be native or forward setNativeProps to a native component at invariant.` Don't really have the time at the moment to learn this stuff properly so just going with what works for now. I like understanding code 110% before using it.

Comment: @Lance there are *abstract* benefits of using stateless components https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.8rjska3v0 . But i think the real question is whether you **really need** to create separate components or not?

Comment: ok thank you. I dont see why i would. I think the way I have it now is ok.